# trouble reading individual characters from input file

Tags: c++

I am trying to create multiple binary trees from a single input file. The input file looks something like:

```
ABCDEFG

JUHSKDHFG

HDSNURHLNF

JNDKFJBJNF
```

Each line represents a different tree, so I have to read in each character individually. The code I have now only reads the first letter of each line and creates a single tree out of the first letter. How do I read the whole line as one tree, then start over again with the next line?

This is the code I have right now:

```
 int main()
    {
        BinaryTree <char> BT;
        char ch;
        string line;
        ifstream myfile("input.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while(getline(myfile, line)
            {
                while(myfile.get(ch))
                {
                    BT.InsertData(ch);
                    if(ch = '\n')
                        break;
                }
            }    
            cout << "Preorder: ";
            BT.PrintPreorder();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Inorder: ";
            BT.PrintInorder();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Postorder: ";
            BT.PrintPostorder();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Reverse Inorder: ";
            BT.PrintReverseInorder();
            cout << endl;    
            BT.PrintPrintTree();
            cout << endl;    
            myfile.close();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: And... ? A question? Is it your intent to ignore every line with actual data and finish each outer-loop pass with tree with a single newline? given your input data, that appears to be what will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this instead:

```
int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("input.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            if (line.empty())
                continue;

            BinaryTree <char> BT;
            for(string::iterator iter = line.begin(); iter != line.end(); ++iter)
                BT.InsertData(*iter);

            cout << "Preorder: ";
            BT.PrintPreorder();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Inorder: ";
            BT.PrintInorder();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Postorder: ";
            BT.PrintPostorder();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Reverse Inorder: ";
            BT.PrintReverseInorder();
            cout << endl;    
            BT.PrintPrintTree();
            cout << endl;    
        }    
    }
    return 0;
}
```